# App with different design in mobile/tablet

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, apk

I'm doing an app that will be very complex. It will have different layouts for the mobile and the tablet and I don't know the best way to do it.

I've read you can publish two different apks, one for mobile and the other for tablet but people don't recommend it.

Should I do two different layouts with two different classes? Or maybe two apks as i said before?

Is there any other way to do it?

Hope I've explained because I'm Spanish and my english is not the best.

Thaankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create layout folders to place your tablet xml files.

```
res/layout-sw600dp/   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw600dp-port/   # For 7” tablets in portrait (600dp wide or bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp-port/  # For 10” tablets
```

More info https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/2CpwdBJ8e6B

You don't need any class to manage it. If device is 7" tablet it will use the layout from res/layout-sw600dp/ or res/layout-sw600dp-port/

Comment: Actually -sw600dp for 7" tablets, -sw720dp for 9" tablets and -sw800dp for 10" tablets.

Comment: To make the mobile and tablet layout works with the same class, the buttons, textviews and other views should have the same ID in both layouts? Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use Butterknife librqry to be sure a view is in both layouts

Answer (score 0):

If the app is just different on the design end of it, what you can do is put handlers in to detect what type of screen it is on, if it is on a screen of x size of bigger, you can trigger the view to display the tablet ui.

I think if the apps are completely different then you should be having 2 different apks.

I could be wrong but this is what i think off the top of my head. :)